# How can I create keyboard shortcuts to run commands in a terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering is it possible to bind say <kbd>F5</kbd> to output `sudo apt-get update` so I can press one key to write this into the terminal?

Comment: Why not use alias? refer to man alias for details

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to `~/.inputrc":

```
"\e[15~": "sudo apt-get update\n"
```

The character sequence to put in the beginning can be gotten by using `od -c <<< "`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>`"` and changing the `033` that shows up to `\e`. The change won't take effect until you open a new shell though.

Comment: bind '"\e[[E": "sudo apt-get update\n"'

Comment: using ~.inputrc didnt work but the finding the key thing with od -c did work

Comment: extra space will render "bash: alias: sudo apt-get update: not found"        it should be alias update= sudo apt-get update'             "just removed one space between = and sudo"'

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to assign shortcuts:  `alias`

```
alias update= 'sudo apt-get update' >> enter or return
```

So now if you type "update" (without the quotes) in the terminal it will automatically run update.  "alias" is not needed unless you are assigning the shortcut.

```
alias {the name of the shortcut}= '{the command line}'
alias agi= 'sudo apt-get install'
```

Remember one thing though; try the shortcut name in the command line first to make sure it is not already a terminal command.

"install" is already a terminal command itself, this is why agi was used.

I just came across your post and it is quite a bit late for my response, but maybe this will help others if you see this response or not.